# Maaping result of stored procedure to constructor in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

In Entity Framework I am mapping result of a stored procedure to a complex type of my class. I want to assign stored procedure's results directly to the constructor of the class rather than a complex type. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what you're trying to do... when you have a stored proc, you tell EF what type to map to; the EF runtime will instantiate your complex type (a class) and set its properties... there's nothing to "assign" to your constructor..... that's done by the EF runtime....

Comment: Yes, I dont want to set the properties to complex type. I want to set that through constructor. Is that possilbe?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I don't see any way you could change the behavior of EF .

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. EF doesn't support constructor with parameters. You must expose default constructor and accessible setter for each property.